# Visual Studio 2015 / Visual Assist autocomplete behaviour

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-2015, visual-assist

When I type a word e.g. "cat", and then start typing another word at the start "ccat" and then use autocomplete (press enter with a suggestion selected, e.g. "cout"), the entire first word will be replaced, so I end up with just "cout".

This is not ok. How do I make it stop?

(I would like to end up with "coutcat" instead.)

I'm not sure whether Visual Studio or Visual Assist are responsible for this (it seems to happen with Visual Assist disabled too, but only sometimes?? o.O ).

Comment: This issue is still not fixed until vs2022

Answer (score 1):

That might be the result of Visual Assist completion behavior.

Try changing the `CompletionOverwriteBehavior` setting in the registry for Visual Assist to `01`.

See http://docs.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W640

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Sorry -- I missed that it also happens with VA disabled.  If it happens when VA is disabled, then problem must lie somewhere else...

Comment: Have you found an solution yet? I am having the same issue and it is seriously pissing me off...